# Driving a LCD from a Basic Stamp 2 microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, integrated-circuit

I'm not able to drive a [UP018D01](http://www.midas-components.com/pdf/UP018D01.pdf) LCD Display (www.ic72.com/pdf_file/u/590916.pdf) with my Basic Stamp II microcontroller.

The first step I'm trying to do is to switch ON the LCD backlight.
According to the UP018D01 datasheet we have to send +5 VDC

So I connected UP018D01's GND to BS2 's VSS and UP018D01's HI to BS2's P9.
Then I ran the folliwing code :

```
' {$STAMP BS2}
' {$PBASIC 2.5}
main:
HIGH 9
GOTO main
```

Unfortunately the backlight is OFF! What can I do? Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to drive the backlight from a microcontroller pin. A typical uC pin will only source a maximum of ~20mA, your backlight may require ~100mA.

If it was an LED based backlight you would do something like connect the backlight directly to a supply voltage through the necessary current limiting resistor.
If you wanted to switch it you would have to use an external transistor to handle the current controlled from the pin.

**However**, it appears your backlight is **CCFL** (cold cathode fluorescent tube) based, and these require a more complex circuit to generate the high voltage required to drive them. It looks like you need ~190V.
From the [datasheet](http://www.midas-components.com/pdf/UP018D01.pdf):

[image: CCFL]

So you will need to look into CCFL driving circuits - this [LT app note](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Application%20Note/an65f.pdf) is not a bad place to start reading.

Or if you don't like the idea of that, you could simply grab a display with an LED backlight, there are thousands to choose from - Displaytech make some decent cheap colour TFT screens. The SDT024BTFT is one of their latest offerings and of a similar size/resolution to your LCD.